# trying to finish a game of billiards

Tags: processing

hey guys im making a billiard game and for the most part im finished but i just cant seem to figure out a few last steps basically everything is right except these specifics. Can anyone please help im so close.

At any point, pressing the ‘c’ button on the keyboard will clear the game, allowing the player to try again

Step 1- First left click of the mouse should display a white cue ball centered where the mouse was when clicked.

Step 2 - Second left click of the mouse should display a target ball centered where the mouse was when clicked.  The target ball should be a different color then the cue ball.  Note, the target ball should NOT be able to be placed on top of the cue ball.  In this step You should measure the distance between the two balls, so you know how far the billiard ball has to travel

Step 3 - Once both balls are displayed, a left click will launch the cue ball at the target ball.

Step 4 - When the cue ball touches the edge of the target ball, the cue ball should stop and the target ball should move in the same direction at the same speed and move the same amount of distance that the cue ball moved
Step 5 - now that all the action is happened, you can reset the entire app, set it back to step 3, or do nothing and inform the user to hit the C button.

here is my code i would really appreciate the help everyone.

```
ball whiteBall, blackBall;
int click;
String msg;
Boolean moving = false;
int difx, dify;
float cdistance;
int steps = 20;
void setup(){
   click=0;
   size(600,400);
   background(16,77,27);
   whiteBall = new ball(35,#ffffff);
   blackBall = new ball(35,#000000);
   msg="";
}

void mouseClicked(){
  if(!moving){
 click++; 
  }
}

void draw(){
  background(20,100,20);
  String msg;
  fill(0,0,0);





 fill(200,200,200);
 noStroke();  
 blackBall.xpos=(300 );
 blackBall.ypos=height/2;
 blackBall.update();
 if(click==0){
  whiteBall.xpos=mouseX;
  whiteBall.ypos=mouseY;
 }else if(click==1){
   difx = whiteBall.xpos-blackBall.xpos;
   dify = whiteBall.ypos-blackBall.ypos;
 }else if(click==2){
  cdistance = dist(whiteBall.xpos,whiteBall.ypos,blackBall.xpos,blackBall.ypos);
   if (cdistance>blackBall.ballDiam/2){
    moving = true;
    whiteBall.xpos-=difx/steps;
    whiteBall.ypos-=dify/steps;
   }else{
      moving = false;
      whiteBall.visible=false;
      click=3;
   } 
 }
 whiteBall.update();
}

class ball{
  int xpos, ypos;
  color myColor;
  int ballDiam;
  boolean visible = true;
  ball(int tempdiam, color tempColor){
    myColor=tempColor;
    ballDiam=tempdiam;
  }

   void update(){
   if(visible){
    fill(myColor);
    ellipse(xpos,ypos,ballDiam,ballDiam);
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: Which language is the code written in?

Comment: seriously people are trolling on stack overflow now, if u cant or dont want to help why comment in the thread. dont turn this place into yahoo answers.......i posted this in the processing forum so its obviously processing

Comment: @user3522502 Sorry, I wasn't paying enough attention and thought the question was missing a language tag.

Comment: To place the ball where you click the mouse, see this: http://www.learningprocessing.com/examples/chapter-3/example-3-2/ . To calculate distance and direction see PVectors here: http://www.processing.org/tutorials/pvector/ . For collision detection, See this: http://www.processing.org/examples/circlecollision.html That should cover all 4 steps. You can take care of the tiny details (like how many times left mouse button has been clicked. Hint: Booleans, or counter).

Comment: You can complain about not getting the answers you want, but you didn't actually ask a question. Recommended reading: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Answer (score 0):

To detect when you've hit the ball, use dist(pos1.x, pos1.y, pos2.x, pos2.y) and compare it to (size1 + size2). if dist() is smaller, they have collided and you change the velocity.